# Can CSS default font-size be changed by the user

Tags: css

[mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size) says that 
**xx-small, x-small, small, medium, large, x-large, xx-large, xxx-large**
Absolute-size keywords, based on the user's default font size (which is medium).

and medium is 16px [by many sources](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-default-font-size-of-HTML)

My question is: can this medium = 16px mapping be changed by the user? and what is the increment between these values? i.e. if medium is 16px and small is 14px?

Comment: Medium is 16px, yes, that's the default, but can be changed, and the CSS keywords will be based on that new value. On Firefox, go to `about:preferences` in General, you can adjust the font size in "Language and Appearance". In Chrome, head to `chrome://settings/`, and in Appearance you have a "Font size" option. Not too sure about Safari, probably linked to OS-level settings.

Comment: All other browsers that I know of can do it too. MS Edge is one notable exception. Not sure why they didn't built it into that one; IE had it. @chriskirknielsen Why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @MrLister Oh I was only listing examples, not being exhaustive. I thought MS Edge would let you do it, though, that's surprising. Sure, I'll post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Medium is 16px, yes, that's the default, but can be changed, and the CSS keywords will be based on that new value. Here are a few examples (non-exhaustive):

- On Firefox, go to `about:preferences` in General, you can adjust the font size in "Language and Appearance".
- In Chrome, head to `chrome://settings/`, and in Appearance you have a "Font size" option.
- Not too sure about Safari, probably linked to OS-level settings.
- Mr Lister pointed out MS Edge doesn't have that option. Maybe that's OS-level as well. (I am able to set it in the new MS Edge though, released for Mac, since it now works pretty much like Chrome).

Comment: True, the version of Edge I was looking at was the "classic" version, which is currently the standard for Windows. (The Chrome-based version still requires a separate download.)